# Trouble in configuring nested routes in react router dom v5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm having trouble configuring my react-router I'm building a dashboard with 2 pages with nested routes. The first page is the main page with all the protected routes and the second login with unprotected routes. The problem I'm facing is when I place the `exact` prop on AuthRoute in the Routes component I won't be able to navigate to all the protected routes but I can navigate to login page. If I remove the `exact` prop I'll be able to navigate to all the protected routes but I can't navigate to the login page. I tried purring the exact on both components it won't work as well

this is may Routes component with two pages Main with all protected routes such as Dashboard and logIn page with another route reset-page

```
function Routes({ ColorModeContext }) {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <AuthRoute
          path="/"
          ColorModeContext={ColorModeContext}
          component={Main}
        />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path="*">
          <div className="center">
            <Box pb={2}>
              <Typography variant="h3">Page Not Found (-_-)</Typography>
            </Box>
            <Button variant="contained" onClick={() => window.history.back()}>
              Go Back
            </Button>
          </div>
        </Route>
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

this is my AuthRoute that separates protected routes from unprotected routes

```
const AuthRoute = ({ component: Component, authStatus = true, ...rest }) => {
  const { ColorModeContext, ...other } = rest;
  return (
    <Route
      {...other}
      render={(props) =>
        authStatus ? (
          <Component {...props} ColorModeContext={ColorModeContext} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/login" />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};
```

here's the main page with all the routes

```
const Main = ({ props }) => {
  const { path } = useRouteMatch();

  return (
    <Box component="main" sx={{ flexGrow: 1, p: 3 }}>
      <DrawerHeader />
      <Switch>
        <Route exact path={path} component={Home} />
        <Route path={`${path}/exam-results`} component={ExamResults} />
        <Route path={`${path}/new-reg`} component={Registration} />
        //...more components
      </Switch>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

here's the login page

```
const LogIn = ({ props }) => {
  const { path } = useRouteMatch();

  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path={path} component={LogInForm} />
      <Route path={`${path}/reset-password`} component={ResetPassForm} />
    </Switch>
  );
};
```

Comment: Why do you've `<Swtich>` in different places instead of having it in your main page ?

Comment: the components are being rendered on the same frame take the idea of Material UI Tabs changing the route on tab change so if I put the components in one switch the frame is lost on route change @KavinduVIndika